# Selecting only trees that are close to road from another layer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, proximity

I have two layers. First one consists of trees in a map, and second one consists of roads - polygons. I would like to select trees that are for instance 2m near the polygon.

Would you please give me a concept how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is creating a 2 meter buffer in your polygon and intersecting your trees with it. Follow these steps:

1. In Qgis, go to Vector -> geoprocessing tools -> fixed distance buffer
2. Use the roads layer as input, set the distance (Be aware that the distance's units will vary depending on your projection)
3. Run and wait the processing
4. Use the buffer layer to make a select by location (Vector -> research tools -> select by location)

And that's it!

Comment: Projection should be any UTM-based projection, these are using meters as base unit. Otherwise no additions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Forgot to write earlier. It saved me so much time.